# Select query not working when trying fetch records for column with column name 'ssl'

Tags: mysql

Can somebody suggests me what is wrong with this query?

```
mysql> select dom_id, ssl from hosting;
```

I am getting below error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'ssl from hosting' at line 1
```

If I remove ssl then query gives result as it should.

Note: Both dom_id and ssl are two columns of hosting table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This one

```
select `dom_id`, `ssl` from hosting;
```

ssl is keyword for mysql. So please use "`" this sign

Answer (score 0):

All MySQL reserves words shloud be between "`" to work properly.